# How to integrate WordPress into Webpack?

Tags: wordpress, webpack, wordpress-theming, frontend

I developed a website front-end using HTML/CSS, JavaScript and Sass or Scss. I used NPM.

I need to put that website into WordPress. I already installed WordPress and put that folder with all my assets(HTML/CSS, JS, Sass etc..) into theme folder.

Now, what do I do now? How do I connect all of this?

I know it's possible because I have worked on a site like this before at work, but not sure how to do it from the ground up.

Webpack -> WordPress. I will watch the files with NPM or webpack, but the hosting will be doing with MAMP - that's how I did it at work anyways.

What should I do?

This is the website code if anything: https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/lovetocodefinal

PS, no WordPress API or any stuff like that, but just as I wrote above.

Comment: WordPress REST API: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/ on the WordPress side an $.ajax or es6 promises in your front-end to request data from the WordPress api endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to this.

It's simple. You need to compile everything and put it in the folders that will be used by WordPress and do WordPress magic to get the styles with functions.

I have made this here: https://github.com/AurelianSpodarec/Webpack-to-WordPress-Starting-Template

It's not perfect, but a good starting point for those who are looking on using Webpack with WordPress.

Answer (score 0):

Old Question, but just had the same one myself. I just built a light Wordpress-Webpack starter. You can use it to build Wordpress-Themes and it will build Scss and copy PHP etc. into the destination of your Themes. It uses Browsersync for easier development. You have complete separation of dev and build :) Maybe this can still help in future. Regards, Fabian

Link: https://github.com/fabiankuhn/webpack-wordpress

Extract from Main Build config (Paths):

```
const themeName = 'test-theme'
const themePath = '/Users/<Username>/<repos>/Test/webpack/wordpress/wp-content/themes'


/*
 * Main Config
 */ 

module.exports = {
  entry: './webpack-entry.js', // Main Entry: Is included in functions.php
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js', // Is included in functions.php

    // Set Path of Wordpress Themes ('.../wp-content/themes') as absolute Path
    path: themePath + '/' + themeName + '/assets',

  },
```

Extract from Wordpress webpack config:

```
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const common = require('./webpack.common.js');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const CopyPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const BrowserSyncPlugin = require('browser-sync-webpack-plugin')

// This Config Exports the FIles with Source Maps for Wordpress Development
module.exports = merge(common, {

  mode: 'development',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map', // Use Source-Maps for Debug

  plugins: [
  // Plugin to Reload Browser According to Proxy 127.0.0.1:8080 (Wordpress PHP)
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3000,
      proxy: '127.0.0.1:8080',
      files: [
        {
          match: [
            '**/*.php',
            '**/*.js',
            '**/*.css',
          ],
        },
      ],
      notify: false,
    },
    {
      reload: true,
    }),

    // Extract CSS
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: '[name].css',
      chunkFilename: '[id].css',
    }),

    // Copy all Files to Entry Output Path except Github, Webpack and 
    // Original Sources (Before Webpack Processing)
    new CopyPlugin([
      {
        from: '../',
        to: '../',
        ignore: [
          '_webpack/**',
          'assets/**',
          '.git/**',
        ],
      },
    ]),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        // Listen for Sass and CSS
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
            },
          },
          // Source Map shows Path in Chrome for Testing
          { loader: 'css-loader', options: { sourceMap: true, importLoaders: 1 } },
          { loader: 'sass-loader', options: { sourceMap: true } },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
});
```